# Plotting with string

Tags: python, string, plot

So I'm trying to plot the following dataframe:

```
        Date                Light (umols)   Time_difference Time_analysis
0       2018-11-17 00:00:00 5000            0 days 00:00:00 fine
1       2018-11-17 00:03:00 5000            0 days 00:03:00 fine
2       2018-11-17 00:06:00 5000            0 days 00:03:00 fine
3       2018-11-17 00:09:00 5000            0 days 00:03:00 fine
4       2018-11-17 00:12:00 5000            0 days 00:03:00 fine
... ... ... ... ...
482785  2021-02-22 23:59:56 634.4           0 days 00:00:00 fine
482786  2021-02-22 23:59:57 574.3           0 days 00:00:00 fine
482787  2021-02-22 23:59:58 598.9           0 days 00:00:00 fine
482788  2021-02-22 23:59:59 676.9           0 days 00:00:00 fine
482789  2021-02-23 00:00:00 5000            0 days 00:03:00 fine
```

Unfortunately I'm struggling to overcome an error. I'm trying to now convert the Light column from strings to numeric values, or floats, at the expense of a `ValueError (could not convert string to float: ' 1,002.3 ')`. My colleague and I have tried various stripping methods with little luck. I've seen various sources that suggest 'try except', but ideally I don't want to do that. I'd like to be able to use loc or iloc to catch that value in the df, and remove the comma so it reads '1002.3' instead. Any suggestions, or is 'try except' the only way to go here?

Answer (score 0):

This will work to strip the comma and convert to float:

```
df['Light (umols)'] = df['Light (umols)'].apply(lambda x: "".join(x.split())).str.replace(',','').astype('float')
```

Comment: I still get that same error. I'm considering potentially using a for loop to say 'for every value in the column over 999, or that has a comma, remove it so it it just reads 1000', for example. Would that work?

Comment: Ah now I see, there are redundant whitespaces in the string. I've updated the answer Try this.